# Gimli, make it even shorter?

Tags: code-golf, cryptography

I'm one of the authors of Gimli. We already have a 2-tweet (280 chars) version in C but I would like to see how small it can get.

Gimli ([paper](https://ia.cr/2017/630),[website](https://gimli.cr.yp.to)) is a high speed with high security level cryptographic permutation design that will be presented at the [Conference on Cryptographic Hardware and Embedded Systems (CHES) 2017](https://ches.iacr.org/2017/) (September 25-28).

## The task

> As usual: to make the smalled usable implementation of Gimli in the language of your choice.
>
> It should be able to **take as input 384 bits** (or 48 bytes, or 12 unsigned int...) and **return (may modify in place if you use pointers) the result of Gimli** applied on these 384 bits.

Input conversion from decimal, hexadecimal, octal or binary is allowed.

### Potential corner cases

Integer encoding is assumed to be little-endian (e.g. what you probably already have).

You may rename `Gimli` into `G` but it must still be a function call.

### Who wins?

This is code-golf so the shortest answer in bytes wins!
Standard rules apply of course.

A reference implementation is provided below.

### Note

Some concern has been raised:

> "hey gang, please implement my program for free in other languages so I don't have to" (thx to @jstnthms)

My answer is as follow:

> I can easily do it in Java, C#, JS, Ocaml... It is more for the fun. Currently We (the Gimli team) have it implemented (and optimized) on AVR, Cortex-M0, Cortex-M3/M4, Neon, SSE, SSE-unrolled, AVX, AVX2, VHDL and Python3. :)

---

### About Gimli

#### The state

Gimli applies a sequence of rounds to a 384-bit state. The state is represented as a parallelepiped with dimensions 3×4×32 or, equivalently, as a 3×4 matrix of 32-bit words.

[image: state]

Each round is a sequence of three operations:

- a non-linear layer, specifically a 96-bit SP-box applied to each column;
- in every second round, a linear mixing layer;
- in every fourth round, a constant addition.

#### The non-linear layer.

The SP-box consists of three sub-operations: rotations of the first and second words; a 3-input nonlinear T-function; and a swap of the first and third words.

[image: SP]

#### The linear layer.

The linear layer consists of two swap operations, namely Small-Swap and Big-Swap. Small-Swap occurs every 4 rounds starting from the 1st round. Big-Swap occurs every 4 rounds starting from the 3rd round.

[image: Linear]

#### The round constants.

There are 24 rounds in Gimli, numbered 24,23,...,1. When the round number r is 24,20,16,12,8,4 we XOR the round constant (0x9e377900 XOR r) to the first state word.

[image]

#### reference source in C

```c
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t rotate(uint32_t x, int bits)
{
  if (bits == 0) return x;
  return (x << bits) | (x >> (32 - bits));
}

extern void gimli(uint32_t *state)
{
  int round;
  int column;
  uint32_t x;
  uint32_t y;
  uint32_t z;

  for (round = 24; round > 0; --round)
  {
    for (column = 0; column < 4; ++column)
    {
      x = rotate(state[    column], 24);
      y = rotate(state[4 + column],  9);
      z =        state[8 + column];

      state[8 + column] = x ^ (z << 1) ^ ((y&z) << 2);
      state[4 + column] = y ^ x        ^ ((x|z) << 1);
      state[column]     = z ^ y        ^ ((x&y) << 3);
    }

    if ((round & 3) == 0) { // small swap: pattern s...s...s... etc.
      x = state[0];
      state[0] = state[1];
      state[1] = x;
      x = state[2];
      state[2] = state[3];
      state[3] = x;
    }
    if ((round & 3) == 2) { // big swap: pattern ..S...S...S. etc.
      x = state[0];
      state[0] = state[2];
      state[2] = x;
      x = state[1];
      state[1] = state[3];
      state[3] = x;
    }

    if ((round & 3) == 0) { // add constant: pattern c...c...c... etc.
      state[0] ^= (0x9e377900 | round);
    }
  }
}
```

#### Tweetable version in C

This might not be the smallest usable implementation but we wanted to have a C standard version (thus no UB, and "usable" in a library).

```c
#include<stdint.h>
#define P(V,W)x=V,V=W,W=x
void gimli(uint32_t*S){for(long r=24,c,x,y,z;r;--r%2?P(*S,S[1+y/2]),P(S[3],S[2-y/2]):0,*S^=y?0:0x9e377901+r)for(c=4;c--;y=r%4)x=S[c]<<24|S[c]>>8,y=S[c+4]<<9|S[c+4]>>23,z=S[c+8],S[c]=z^y^8*(x&y),S[c+4]=y^x^2*(x|z),S[c+8]=x^2*z^4*(y&z);}
```

#### Test vector

The following input generated by

```c
for (i = 0;i < 12;++i) x[i] = i * i * i + i * 0x9e3779b9;
```

and "printed" values by

```c
for (i = 0;i < 12;++i) {
  printf("%08x ",x[i])
  if (i % 4 == 3) printf("\n");
}
```

thus:

```
00000000 9e3779ba 3c6ef37a daa66d46 
78dde724 1715611a b54cdb2e 53845566 
f1bbcfc8 8ff34a5a 2e2ac522 cc624026
```

should return:

```
ba11c85a 91bad119 380ce880 d24c2c68 
3eceffea 277a921c 4f73a0bd da5a9cd8 
84b673f0 34e52ff7 9e2bef49 f41bb8d6
```

Comment: A tweet is 140 chars, not a 280

Comment: I know, which is why it fits into 2 ;) https://twitter.com/TweetGimli .

Comment: "hey gang, please implement my program for free in other languages so I don't have to"

Comment: hahaha Nah I already have it in Python, and I can easily do it in Java, C#, JS. It is more for the fun. :)

Comment: Currently I have it implemented on AVR, Cortex-M0, Cortex-M3/M4, Neon, SSE, SSE-unrolled, AVX, AVX2 and Python3.

Comment: The [reference code](https://gimli.cr.yp.to/spec.html) on the website has a crucial error, `-round` instead of `--round` means that it never terminates. Converting `--` to an en dash is probably not suggested in code :)

Comment: @Shaggy updated.

Comment: "2-tweet" hey, now you have a 1-tweet version!

Comment: my 112-bytes binary version is only 154 bytes in base64.  You can tweet that now.

Comment: and when base85-encoded, it's exactly 140 bytes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### CJam (114 chars)

```
{24{[4/z{[8ZT].{8\#*G8#:Mmd+}__)2*\+.^W%\[_~;&8*\~@1$|2*@@&4*].^Mf%}%z([7TGT]R=4e!=\f=(2654435608R-_4%!*^\@]e_}fR}
```

This is an anonymous block (function): if you want to name it `G` then append `:G`. In CJam assigned names can only be single upper-case letters. There's space to append a comment `e# Gimli in CJam` and have characters left in a single tweet.

[Online test](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qNSerS%25%7B%220123456789abcdef%22f%23Gb%7D%2512%2F~%3AE%3B%0A%0A%7B24%7B%5B4%2Fz%7B%5B8ZT%5D.%7B8%5C%23*G8%23%3AMmd%2B%7D__)2*%5C%2B.%5EW%25%5C%5B_~%3B%268*%5C~%401%24%7C2*%40%40%264*%5D.%5EMf%25%7D%25z(%5B7TGT%5DR%3D4e!%3D%5Cf%3D(2654435608R-_4%25!*%5E%5C%40%5De_%7DfR%7D%0A%0A~_pE%3Dp%0A&input=00000000%209e3779ba%203c6ef37a%20daa66d46%2078dde724%201715611a%20b54cdb2e%2053845566%20f1bbcfc8%208ff34a5a%202e2ac522%20cc624026%0Aba11c85a%2091bad119%20380ce880%20d24c2c68%203eceffea%20277a921c%204f73a0bd%20da5a9cd8%2084b673f0%2034e52ff7%209e2bef49%20f41bb8d6)

#### Dissection

```
{                                e# Define a block
  24{                            e# For R=0 to 23...
    [                            e#   Collect values in an array
      4/z                        e#     Transpose to columns
      {                          e#     Map over each column
        [8ZT].{8\#*G8#:Mmd+}     e#       Rotations, giving [x y z]
        __)2*\+.^W%\             e#       => [y^z x^y x^z*2] [x y z]
        [_~;&8*\~@1$|2*@@&4*].^  e#       => [x' y' z']
        Mf%                      e#       Map out any bits which overflowed
      }%
      z                          e#    Transpose to rows
      ([7TGT]R=4e!=\f=           e#    Permute first row
      (2654435608R-_4%!*^        e#    Apply round constant to first element
      \@                         e#    Put the parts in the right order
    ]e_                          e#  Finish collecting in array and flatten
  }fR
}
```

Comment: For a moment I was thrown of by the fact that the ouput was not in hex (in the online test). :)

Answer (score 16):

## C (gcc), 237 bytes

```c
#define P(a,l)x=a;a=S[c=l>>r%4*2&3];S[c]=x;
r,c,x,y,z;G(unsigned*S){
for(r=24;r;*S^=r--%4?0:0x9e377901+r){
for(c=4;c--;*S++=z^y^8*(x&y))
x=*S<<24|*S>>8,y=S[4]<<9|S[4]>>23,z=S[8],S[8]=x^2*z^4*(y&z),S[4]=y^x^2*(x|z);
S-=4;P(*S,33)P(S[3],222)}}
```

I probably gained bytes with my swapping method, but it's too cute not to use.

Comment: lost or gained?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Gained, making me a loser :)

Comment: Ah ok :P makes sense :P :P

Comment: This is still definitely an improvement, but it's somewhat cheating to use `unsigned` instead of `uint32_t` (and OP's code was somewhat cheating to use `long`) because the idea behind the cipher is that it's highly portable. (In fact, fundamentally this saves a mere 8 bytes).

Comment: @PeterTaylor Even though my code is similar, I'm not really competing against OP's code. I'm working under the rules of PPCG, where it must work with at least an implementation on a platform, and it does with `gcc` on a 32-bit or 64-bit Intel CPU (and probably many more).

Comment: @orlp I really like your column traversal too. :)

Comment: @Biv And this technique, to use a bitshift as a small lookup table is actually a side-channel resistant form of doing lookup tables, so potentially useful in implementing crypto primitives :) Obviously in the way it's used here the access pattern is always consistent and public information, so no reason to worry about cache effects, but the technique is interesting regardless.

Answer (score 4):

### C, 268 chars (268 bytes) using uint32_t

NB Since the original code uses `<stdint.h>` and types `S` as `uint32_t *`, I think the use of `long` is a cheat to get into 280 chars at the cost of the portability which is the reason for using `uint32_t` in the first place. If for fairness of comparison we require consistent use of `uint32_t` and the explicit signature `void gimli(uint32_t *)`, the original code is really 284 chars, and orlp's code is 276 chars.

```c
#include<stdint.h>
#define R(V)x=S[V],S[V]=S[V^y],S[V^y]=x,
void gimli(uint32_t*S){for(uint32_t r=24,x,y,z,*T;r--;y=72>>r%4*2&3,R(0)R(3)*S^=y&1?0x9e377901+r:0)for(T=S+4;T-->S;*T=z^y^8*(x&y),T[4]=y^x^2*(x|z),T[8]=x^2*z^4*(y&z))x=*T<<24|*T>>8,y=T[4]<<9|T[4]>>23,z=T[8];}
```

---

This can be split into two tweets with continuation markers as

```c
#include<stdint.h>
#define R(V)x=S[V],S[V]=S[V^y],S[V^y]=x,
void gimli(uint32_t*S){for(uint32_t r=24,x,y,z,*T;r--;y=72>>r%4*2&3,R(0)R(3)// 1
```

and

```c
*S^=y&1?0x9e377901+r:0)for(T=S+4;T-->S;*T=z^y^8*(x&y),T[4]=y^x^2*(x|z),T[8]=x^2*z^4*(y&z))x=*T<<24|*T>>8,y=T[4]<<9|T[4]>>23,z=T[8];}// 2/2
```

Comment: The use of `long` in *my* version is safe (with respect to portability) because the minimum size of a long is 32 bits by the standard (as opposed to `int`). Rotations of `x` and `y` are done before the cast into `long` at the assignment, making them safe (as the right shift on signed value is CC dependent). The cast when going back to the `uint32_t* S`) gets rid of the upper bits and puts us in the right state :).

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>351</s> <s>343</s> <s>339</s> <s>320</s> <s>318</s> 247 + 56 bytes

Just a near 1:1 port of the reference to start golfing from.

```java
void f(int[]x,int y,int z){int q=x[y];x[y]=x[z];x[z]=q;}

s->{for(int r=24,c,x,y,z;r>0;--r){for(c=0;c<4;x=s[c]<<24|s[c]>>>8,y=s[4+c]<<9|s[4+c]>>>23,z=s[8+c],s[8+c]=x^z<<1^(y&z)<<2,s[4+c]=y^x^(x|z)<<1,s[c++]=z^y^(x&y)<<3);if((r&3)==2){f(s,0,2);f(s,1,3);}if((r&3)<1){f(s,0,1);f(s,2,3);s[0]^=0x9e377900|r;}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVJNb6MwEL3zK6xKjezgIL6kJjLmsoee9tQjAom6UDlNgNqmi0n47VkbEin7ce4gecbveZ5Hz@zLr3LTdlWzf/u48GPXCgX2BvN6xQ9e3TdM8bbx1sRxuv71wBlgh1JK8LPkDTg5wIRUpTL4V8vfQA15o7J8wCYBPa8jOtn0SYdM58QuphptNeb0k0zOvciPtpH9sRLJLJOCZ0DBRW7SU90KKw0EDWPM8IA1HolIfbLZCDSzjPqEJTEZqMxYniRhfLZFmqZbrA0WuxbdnZfKwGGER4NvzQ4viQ7FmCRBAfVqREYBL2epLoYCDmeLBQZjrpvTsdAGW2mDRYjwGkKxihCloZkGSuzjEBFbBNjQ041PghsdLHRoaZn5eUH9YVdFT0873z8LMk3ThSzWXH2/t/lo3IcvSvDmPctBKd4luj6Gjdm7UohS06b6NW@DML@q2TB2gdlNbjzjSRAS1@Vo7sh4TvnafC5f3wZ63f3Z@2/r6UVLVR29tldeZ6ZSNXx49LcDeMA31dkj/hhTGqG/Tx8aiG4/go1nr2Ss6hScm9Hd7f/t/JbhrPzkTJff)

Comment: Why use `Integer` at all? o_O Since you don't use any `Integer` method, there's no reason to not use `int`s here...

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I think just a remnant from me trying Integer.divideUnsigned, but I realised I can have >>>

Comment: `s[0]^=(0x9e377900|r);` (at the very end) -- can't you drop the extra parentheses?

Comment: Same with `s[4+c]>>>(23)`.

Comment: You can make far fewer changes and get 300: `void P(int[]S,int a,int b){int x=S[a];S[a]=S[b];S[b]=x;}void gimli(int[]S){for(int r=24,c,x,y,z;r>0;S[0]^=y<1?0x9e377901+r:0){for(c=4;c-->0;){x=S[c]<<24|S[c]>>>8;y=S[c+4]<<9|S[c+4]>>>23;z=S[c+8];S[c]=z^y^8*(x&y);S[c+4]=y^x^2*(x|z);S[c+8]=x^2*z^4*(y&z);}y=r%4;if(--r%2>0){P(S,0,1+y/2);P(S,3,2-y/2);}}}` . I've basically made the minimal changes necessary to get it to compile. Java's precedence rules aren't very different to C's.

Comment: [Order of Operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Comment: [238](https://tio.run/##lVHBbqMwFLznK6xIrTBxEDhITdaYHnroaU89UpCoS1bOJobapgskfHv6DK1U9bay5DeescfP40P5Xq7rplKH179XeWpqbdEBuKC18hjsWyWsrFXgs6Z9OUqBxLE0Bv0upTobW1pg3mv5ivaeVDbLOwIF9dM84LMrb7zL@py5CdDg0JDzNzZ@Hn@olWlPlU4mg/SRo6tZp@d9rZ0l0pzGRJCO9GRgOg3Zeq3xpAoeMpHErOcmi1ciT5LdZUZpmtINGYDfworMhXfF4NPC628H7Mdk3sn7oiu87gIUBUqsVjkfih6o2x77W9yBh3Om8cUBMN4yuff0Tcw5hTY8Q0JCMXMgIhvMxllNoi8xmkXqRJOFecHDbldt7u52YXjRbBzHK1ugz3C/J3qCiL0nq6X6k@UGnxdoCqjkqvo3wYjmzCUkIYcFmvICJJOIsqfe2OoU1K0NGjCw8Duu48398ibcds9q@WsCaEnKTMKbMYaac@nDWEn/q8OXHRg/BqUQVWO9EsPqp/NRefjn7fi/rweHcTFePwA "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 231 bytes

```js
s=>{for(r=25;--r;[a,b,c,d,...e]=s,s=r&1?s:r&2?[c,d,a,b,...e]:[b,a,d,c,...e],s[0]^=r&3?0:0x9e377900|r)for(c=4;c--;x=s[c]<<24|s[c]>>>8,y=s[j=c+4]<<9|s[j]>>>23,z=s[c+8],s[c+8]=x^z*2^(y&z)*4,s[j]=y^x^(x|z)*2,s[c]=z^y^(x&y)*8);return s}
```

#### Demo

```js
let f =

s=>{for(r=25;--r;[a,b,c,d,...e]=s,s=r&1?s:r&2?[c,d,a,b,...e]:[b,a,d,c,...e],s[0]^=r&3?0:0x9e377900|r)for(c=4;c--;x=s[c]<<24|s[c]>>>8,y=s[j=c+4]<<9|s[j]>>>23,z=s[c+8],s[c+8]=x^z*2^(y&z)*4,s[j]=y^x^(x|z)*2,s[c]=z^y^(x&y)*8);return s}

console.log(
  f([
    0x00000000, 0x9e3779ba, 0x3c6ef37a, 0xdaa66d46,
    0x78dde724, 0x1715611a, 0xb54cdb2e, 0x53845566,
    0xf1bbcfc8, 0x8ff34a5a, 0x2e2ac522, 0xcc624026
  ])
  .map(x=>(x >>> 0).toString(16)).join(' ')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

### 32-bit x86 assembler (112 bytes)

(__cdecl calling convention)

```
            pusha
            mov     ecx, 9E377918h
    loc_6:  mov     esi, [esp+24h]
            push    esi
            push    4
            pop     ebx
    loc_E:  lodsd
            ror     eax, 8
            mov     ebp, [esi+0Ch]
            rol     ebp, 9
            mov     edx, [esi+1Ch]
            push    eax
            push    ebp
            lea     edi, [edx+edx]
            and     ebp, edx
            shl     ebp, 2
            xor     edi, ebp
            xor     eax, edi
            mov     [esi+1Ch], eax
            pop     ebp
            pop     eax
            push    eax
            push    ebp
            xor     ebp, eax
            or      eax, edx
            shl     eax, 1
            xor     ebp, eax
            mov     [esi+0Ch], ebp
            pop     ebp
            pop     eax
            xor     edx, ebp
            and     eax, ebp
            shl     eax, 3
            xor     edx, eax
            push    edx
            dec     ebx
            jnz     short loc_E
            pop     esi
            pop     ebp
            pop     ebx
            pop     eax
            pop     edi
            mov     dl, cl
            and     dl, 3
            jnz     short loc_5B
            xchg    eax, ebx
            xchg    esi, ebp
            xor     eax, ecx
    loc_5B: cmp     dl, 2
            jnz     short loc_63
            xchg    eax, ebp
            xchg    esi, ebx
    loc_63: stosd
            xchg    eax, ebx
            stosd
            xchg    eax, ebp
            stosd
            xchg    eax, esi
            stosd
            dec     cl
            jnz     short loc_6
            popa
            retn
```

Tweetable version (z85-format Base85 encoding):

```
v7vb1h>C}HbQuA91y51A:oWYw48G)?I=H/]rGf9Na>sA.DWu06{6f#TEC^CM:#IeA-cstx7:>!VfVf#u*YB&mP(tuCl*+7eENBP)$:)Lh!k}t$^wM51j%LDf$HMAg2bB^MQP
```